# Sending a Javascript variable by a hyperlink

Tags: javascript

Okay, this sorta plays off my previous question: [javascript custom alert box transparency issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173417/javascript-custom-alert-box-transparency-issue)

I'm trying to get it so that there are three links that open the box instead of one. I'm trying to figure out how to send a variable through these links and then run a switch statement to determine what should be displayed in the box.

Comment: Instead of linking us to another question to find out what you're asking, you should post your full question here.

Comment: You could use a localStorage, cookies, or even GET data from the URL. Or just look at the URL/URI to determine what you should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer (based off of the markup in your previous question): just pass a parameter to your function that you're calling when you're doing:

```
<a href="javascript:DlgShow('someParameter');">Open</a>
```

A longer answer, you should move this out of the `href` attribute and perhaps even out of the anchor tag and into a button.  Then, instead of doing inline javascript, add an event listener.  For your example, three buttons that display something in an `alert` based on a switch case:

```
<button id="one">One</button>
<button id="two">Two</button>
<button id="three">Three</button>
```

And then your javascript:

```
(function() {
    document.getElementById('one').addEventListener('click', oneClickEvent);
    document.getElementById('two').addEventListener('click', twoClickEvent);
    document.getElementById('three').addEventListener('click', threeClickEvent);

    function oneClickEvent() {
        showAlert('one');
    }

    function twoClickEvent() {
        showAlert('two');
    }

    function threeClickEvent() {
        showAlert('three');
    }

    function showAlert(item) {
        switch(item)
        [...]
    }
})();
```

Comment: Managed to get the first example to work.